# Setting up Gentoo : Entering the new Envriontment step (chrooting)

Tags: installation, livecd, gentoo

I'm a `Windows` person trying to get to know `Linux` and having a go at installing `Gentoo` on a VM.

I seem to have got [stuck at a simple step](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=6), *Entering the new Environment* :

When I enter the first of the following commands as instructed:

```
# chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash
# source /etc/profile
# export PS1="(chroot) $PS1"
```

I am told

```
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash' : No such file or directory
```

Can anyone explain what that means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell it means you skipped something or did something wrong earlier in the process. I've installed Gentoo many times and the handbook has always been right on. Especially check that you unpacked the stage tarball properly.

Comment: It would come as no surprise lol!  Thanks I'll retrace my steps.